# Highcharts JS in IE 7 doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In my following code example the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility) plot does not appear in Internet Explorer 7.
http://jsfiddle.net/bVGTS/

Answer (score 2):

You had a comma after `animation:false,` - Internet Explorer does not like this.

[Here is a corrected JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ryzj/).

Comment: @Árvai Zsolti a tip: press f12 in IE to open js console and then look for errors there (you may need to run the program again)